# No real $x,y$ such that $(x+y)^2+(x-2)^2+(y-2)^2=4$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Here's the context of this problem.

> Solve:
>
> $x^2=y^3-3y^2+2y$
>
> $y^2=x^3-3x^2+2x$

We subtract the second equation from the first and obtain $$(x-y)(x^2+y^2+xy-2x-2y+2)=0$$ The first factor yields the solutions $0,2\pm\sqrt2$ and the second one can be rewritten as $$(x+y)^2+(x-2)^2+(y-2)^2=4$$ I have checked Wolfram Alpha and it tells me that there are no more real solution to the above system.This means that the above equation has no solution.Now I have to prove it.

Obviously,none of the expressions $(x+y)^2,(x-2)^2,(y-2)^2$ can be $4$ otherwise the LHS would be larger than $4$. Hence,we have the inequalities $$|x+y|<2$$$$|x-2|<2$$$$|y-2|<2$$ which(unless I am mistaken) yield $$0<x<2$$ $$0<y<2$$ I cannot proceed any further.Perhaps there is some clever way to write the whole expression solely using squares but I cannot see it immediately.

I would appreciate it if the method used to solve this is elementary.Some help will be appreciated.

Comment: *Without* any calculus, correct?

Comment: @JohnD,yes,correct.

Comment: if you are looking for non trivial solution of course.. (0,0)

Comment: $f(x,y)=(x+y)^2+(x-2)^2+(y-2)^2>4$ for all $x,y$. In fact, the minimum of $f$ is $16/3$ and occurs at $(2/3,2/3)$.

Comment: @Chinny84,oh,the first factor yields that solution.Forgot to mention it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Write $$f(x) = (x+y)^2 + (x-2)^2 + (y-2)^2 - 4$$ for a fixed $y$.

The zeros of $f(x)$ are the solutions you want. If you compute the discriminant of $f(x)=0$, you get $-8y^2 + 16y -32$. This is negative for every $y$, hence $f(x)$ has no real solution for every $y$. This suffice!